# Why can't my shell script while loop be used normally?

Tags: linux, shell

I am using the software while loop, the following is my script：

```
cat ./list.txt |
  while read id
  do
    (
      ribotricer detect-orfs --bam /home/leelee/share/mapping/genome/${id}Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam  --ribotricer_index /home/leelee/share/ORFfind/ribotricer/noncode/twodb_candidate_orfs.tsv --prefix ${id}.ribotricer --phase_score_cutoff 0.440
    )
  done
```

The error shows that the bam file I entered cannot be found, but I am sure this file exists.I used the following script and found that I output a strange file name：

```
cat ./list.txt |
  while read id
  do
    (
      echo /home/leelee/share/mapping/genome/${id}Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
    )
  done
```

The following is the output

```
Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bamnome/SRR1257256
Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bamnome/SRR1257257
Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bamnome/SRR1257258
Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bamnome/SRR1257259
Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bamnome/SRR1257260
Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bamnome/SRR1257261
Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bamnome/SRR1257262
```

This is obviously not the output I want. Why does this happen (this script was able to run normally before) and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could it be that `list.txt` has CRLF line endings?

Comment: I tried cat another list and found that I can get the desired output, It should be a problem with the list.txt file, but how do I modify this file?

Comment: [`dos2unix`](https://www.mankier.com/1/dos2unix)